# event.detail is undefined in Lightning:recordEditForm submit event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, event, lightning-events, lightning-recordeditform

I'm trying to get field values at Lightning:recordEditForm onSubmit() event.In the [documentation example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) it shows below.

[image]

my onSubmit event handler as below,
[image]

I end up getting error,

[image]

> [event.detail is undefined]

Not too sure why I'm getting this error, I hope it's correct as per documentation.

Question: Why do I get this error, seems not a spelling mistake?

Also wondering where to find any documentation on what's available in Lightning:recordEditForm onSubmit event's parameters? Lightning component Library Documentation seems not covering much information this regard.

Appreciate any help, suggestions on this. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference documentation is incorrect; i.e.: of lightning web component: [`lightning-record-edit-form`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation), where to access the data we use:

```
console.log('fields: ' + JSON.stringify(event.detail.fields));
```

And in your example, you are working with lightning aura component: [`lightning:recordEditForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleRecordCreate), here the syntax is:

```
console.log('fields: ' + JSON.stringify(event.getParam('fields')));
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help @Raul, got misled by same same name. By any chance do you know where I could find what attributes are included in **fields** , couldn't find any documentation around it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, and it returns an object or map of fields, you could find more information on documentation tab of [component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation).